# Cross validation with grid search returns worse results than default

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I'm using scikitlearn in Python to run some basic machine learning models. Using the built in GridSearchCV() function, I determined the "best" parameters for different techniques, yet many of these perform worse than the defaults. I include the default parameters as an option, so I'm surprised this would happen.

For example:

```
from sklearn import svm, grid_search
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier(verbose=1)
parameters = {'learning_rate':[0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1],  
              'min_samples_split':[2,5,10,20], 
              'max_depth':[2,3,5,10]}
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(gbc, parameters)
t0 = time()
clf.fit(X_crossval, labels)
print "Gridsearch time:", round(time() - t0, 3), "s"
print clf.best_params_
# The output is: {'min_samples_split': 2, 'learning_rate': 0.01, 'max_depth': 2}
```

This is the same as the defaults, except max_depth is 3. When I use these parameters, I get an accuracy of 72%, compared to 78% from the default.

One thing I did, that I will admit is suspicious, is that I used my entire dataset for the cross validation. Then after obtaining the parameters, I ran it using the same dataset, split into 75-25 training/testing.

Is there a reason my grid search overlooked the "superior" defaults?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your `cross_validation` scheme?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm pretty new to this and I don't know what terms I would need to describe it. I followed the example given in the scikitlearn manual for the function. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV I know it defaults to a three-fold cross validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running cross-validation on your entire dataset for parameter and/or feature selection can definitely cause problems when you test on the same dataset.  It looks like that's at least part of the problem here.  Running CV on a subset of your data for parameter optimization, and leaving a holdout set for testing, is good practice.

Assuming you're using the [`iris`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html) dataset (that's the dataset used in the example in your comment link), here's an example of how `GridSearchCV` parameter optimization is affected by first making a holdout set with [`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

iris = datasets.load_iris()
gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier()
parameters = {'learning_rate':[0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1], 
              'min_samples_split':[2,5,10,20], 
              'max_depth':[2,3,5,10]}

clf = GridSearchCV(gbc, parameters)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

print(clf.best_params_)
# {'learning_rate': 1, 'max_depth': 2, 'min_samples_split': 2}
```

Now repeat the grid search using a random training subset:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, 
                                                 test_size=0.33, 
                                                 random_state=42)

clf = GridSearchCV(gbc, parameters)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(clf.best_params_)
# {'learning_rate': 0.01, 'max_depth': 5, 'min_samples_split': 2}
```

I'm seeing much higher classification accuracy with both of these approaches, which makes me think maybe you're using different data - but the basic point about performing parameter selection while maintaining a holdout set is demonstrated here.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Like you said though, even the one that used the entire dataset still showed higher accuracy, so I think it's something more. I asked some other questions recently, and another big problem with my data is I didn't normalize it, so that probably lead to some issues too. I'll try all these recommendations and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Kfolds cross_validator
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

iris = datasets.load_iris()
gbc = GradientBoostingClassifier()
parameters = {'learning_rate':[0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1], 
          'min_samples_split':[2,5,10,20], 
          'max_depth':[2,3,5,10]}

cv_test= KFold(n_splits=5)
clf = GridSearchCV(gbc, parameters,cv=cv_test)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

print(clf.best_params_)
```